# Flexible change another prepositon

Tags: meaning, prepositions, context, lexicon

Here is the sentence:
" I argue with you"

Most of the time I have been taught that ARGUE + WITH is the function that I have to remember. But recently I have read some books about lexicon and they encourage to modify with another preposition in any case because they believe if one can master the lexicon can make a beautiful sentence with words. That leads me to another sentence with similar meaning to my first example I guess.

The sentence I have change is:

" I argue against you"

I am quite not sure with the second sentence because I am not a native speaker.
Could you guy explain it for me? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Using "against" or "for" with argue shows you are arguing against or for a particular position you hold; you can't use it to mean you are having an argument with another person as in your example.

> I am arguing with Tom. I am arguing against using the metric system, he is arguing for using the metric system.

If you said "I argue against you" it would imply your arguments were against the very idea of the other person - you could, for instance, say "I argue against you being elected to the board of trustees." It wouldn't mean you were actually having an argument with that person, though.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/argue+against